# How to find Play Framework version of a project?

Tags: scala, playframework, version

I am using Play Framework for an application. I am finding some in inconsistencies with the documentation. Such as, in  the documentation it is written that the constructor of the class *FakeHeaders* should have a *map* of *string* and *seq of string*.
This is written in the Documentation.

`case class FakeHeaders (data: Map[String, Seq[String]]) extends Headers with Product with Serializable`

This is the [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/test/FakeHeaders.html) of the documentation.

But when I am writing it, I am getting a compilation error saying that *FakeHeaders* should have a *seq* instead of a *map*.

This is the error I am getting.

```
[error]  found   : Map[String,Seq[String]]
[error]  required: Seq[(String, Seq[String])]
```

I believe it is because the framework that I am using is old. But I don't know what version I am using. How do I find out the playframework version of an existing project?

Comment: I would say you are using at least [Play 2.1.1](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.FakeHeaders).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `plugins.sbt`:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")`

My version is `2.3.8`.